# What is the reasoning behind the assert statements in the constructor vs. class's main method?

Tags: java, constructor, program-entry-point, assert

[I'm taking this online Java course](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/QandE/creating-answers.html) and don't understand the reasoning behind the different assert sections in the code.

Why are the rankToString assert methods in the class's main method vs. isValidRank methods in the class's constructor?

```
public class Card {
private final int rank;
private final int suit;

// Kinds of suits
public final static int DIAMONDS = 1;
public final static int CLUBS    = 2;
public final static int HEARTS   = 3;
public final static int SPADES   = 4;

// Kinds of ranks
public final static int ACE   = 1;
public final static int DEUCE = 2;
public final static int THREE = 3;
public final static int FOUR  = 4;
public final static int FIVE  = 5;
public final static int SIX   = 6;
public final static int SEVEN = 7;
public final static int EIGHT = 8;
public final static int NINE  = 9;
public final static int TEN   = 10;
public final static int JACK  = 11;
public final static int QUEEN = 12;
public final static int KING  = 13;

public Card(int rank, int suit) {
    assert isValidRank(rank);
    assert isValidSuit(suit);
    this.rank = rank;
    this.suit = suit;
}

public int getSuit() {
    return suit;
}

public int getRank() {
    return rank;
}

public static boolean isValidRank(int rank) {
    return ACE <= rank && rank <= KING;
}

public static boolean isValidSuit(int suit) {
    return DIAMONDS <= suit && suit <= SPADES;
}

public static String rankToString(int rank) {
    switch (rank) {
    case ACE:
        return "Ace";
    case DEUCE:
        return "Deuce";
    case THREE:
        return "Three";
    case FOUR:
        return "Four";
    case FIVE:
        return "Five";
    case SIX:
        return "Six";
    case SEVEN:
        return "Seven";
    case EIGHT:
        return "Eight";
    case NINE:
        return "Nine";
    case TEN:
        return "Ten";
    case JACK:
        return "Jack";
    case QUEEN:
        return "Queen";
    case KING:
        return "King";
    default:
        //Handle an illegal argument.  There are generally two
        //ways to handle invalid arguments, throwing an exception
        //(see the section on Handling Exceptions) or return null
        return null;
    }    
}

public static String suitToString(int suit) {
    switch (suit) {
    case DIAMONDS:
        return "Diamonds";
    case CLUBS:
        return "Clubs";
    case HEARTS:
        return "Hearts";
    case SPADES:
        return "Spades";
    default:
        return null;
    }    
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // must run program with -ea flag (java -ea ..) to
    // use assert statements
    assert rankToString(ACE) == "Ace";
    assert rankToString(DEUCE) == "Deuce";
    assert rankToString(THREE) == "Three";
    assert rankToString(FOUR) == "Four";
    assert rankToString(FIVE) == "Five";
    assert rankToString(SIX) == "Six";
    assert rankToString(SEVEN) == "Seven";
    assert rankToString(EIGHT) == "Eight";
    assert rankToString(NINE) == "Nine";
    assert rankToString(TEN) == "Ten";
    assert rankToString(JACK) == "Jack";
    assert rankToString(QUEEN) == "Queen";
    assert rankToString(KING) == "King";

    assert suitToString(DIAMONDS) == "Diamonds";
    assert suitToString(CLUBS) == "Clubs";
    assert suitToString(HEARTS) == "Hearts";
    assert suitToString(SPADES) == "Spades";

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `assert`s in the `main` method test assertions about static final fields, the `assert`s in the constructor test assertions about non-static final fields. Since assertions about static fields shouldn't be tested every time an object is created and non-static fields need a instance, it makes sense to place the assertions there.

However I would recommend writing jUnit tests instead of using `assert`s.

---

You'll find a [tutorial for jUnit at vogella.com](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JUnit/article.html).

#### Some benefits of jUnit:

- You don't have to mix the tests with the code, which makes the code more readable.
- You can test sequences of function calls, ect. without changing the behaviour of the code (e.g. it's hard to test if an exception is thrown in asserts without adding a try-catch block to the code)
- Most IDEs provide a nice user interface for jUnit
- You have better control when you check your assertions. E.g. you can create 2 `Card`s without checking the assertions in the constructor twice.

Comment: I have not learned about jUnit tests yet. What is wrong with using asserts? Does it cause performance problems?

Comment: Asserts are a C-like thing that nobody actually uses except for C programmers dabbling in Java.  They're intended for testing and should never be left in production code.

The nice thing about JUnit is that it separates test code from production code.  You probably won't learn about JUnit in school, because schools don't teach practical things like that.  But you should definitely teach yourself about it.

Comment: Another clue that this code was written by a C programmer dabbling in Java: they're using ints when an enum is clearly called for.

Comment: And they're testing string equality using the equality operator.  Sheesh!  They get away with it here because they're comparing string literals, but that's not explained and could easily lead you astray.  And returning null to indicate an error is very bad practice.  This must be an ancient tutorial that Sun and Oracle never bothered updating.

Answer (score -1):

`assert` is a java keyword that lets you test some condition (and enforce that it is valid). The format used here is `assert <boolean>`
You will see that that the expression after the `assert` evaluates to a `boolean` in both cases.

You can read more about it in [this Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html).